# WPF, Window resizing as TextBox resizes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I posted this question but the suggested answers do not seem to work. So once again, re-posting it, much simpler version of the XAML. We usually expect the TextBox to resize as the Window resize. I want the "other-way-around" behavior. TextBox that takes the whole Window area. The TextBox grows/shrinks in size, the Window follows. Please suggest on ways doing it.

```
<Window>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox Width="Auto">            
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.SizeToContent"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SizeToContent" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox Width="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True">
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Notice that you have to include `ResizeMode="NoResize"`, because if the user resizes the window manually, the behavior is lost.

Comment: Or you could of course use the size to content functionality, either way could be used, but you may find one works better for you (e.g. the binding version especially if you want some form of value converter in the equation at some point)

Comment: SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" does the job. Nothing else necessary. Thanks HighCore :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774854/wpf-window-resizing-as-textbox-resizes/15774953?noredirect=1#15774953

Comment: @armanali not really. Try resizing the window manually, and then type in the TextBox. You will notice that the behavior is "broken" after you resize the window manually.

Comment: @HighCore, you are right, that's why I removed my comment. So if I want to have both behaviors at the same time ? What do I do ? Do I resort to a more manual method ? INotifyPropertyChanged etc ?

Comment: @Armanali what do you mean with "both behaviors"? It's contradictory, if you let the Window Resize itself according to the `TextBox` then it makes no sense for the user to resize it manually. If you let the user manually resize the Window then it makes no sense for it to be dependant on the size of its contents. These sound like mutually exclusive features. How do you expect to combine them together?

Comment: @HighCore yes and no. If the Window is bigger than the actual text in it and as the user types and reaches the end of the Window and keeps typing I want it to grow in size and I don't want it to shrink its size if the user deletes the text.

Comment: @armanali if you want that sort of behaviour then binding the window width through a value converter that remembers the biggest value thus far may be the way to go, can't vouch for it though as I haven't tested it.

Answer (score -1):

You could give the textbox a name and then bind the window width to the size of the textbox as such:

```
<Window Width="{Binding ElementName=txtbox, Path=ActualWidth}">
   <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <TextBox x:Name="txtbox" Width="Auto">            
      </TextBox>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've not included any code for sizing the textbox (I assume you're going to do that programmatically or so) but with this XAML the window should size to the textbox width.

Comment: -1. I tested your XAML and it doesn't work. Neither the TextBox nor the Window are dynamically resized.